# How can I make React-aria with NextJs new app directory server side rendering work?

Tags: next.js, internationalization, react-aria

I am using Internationalization (i18n) in Server Components. My layout component is like this

```
import LanguageSwitcher from '@/components/common/LanguageSwitcher';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';

import React from 'react';
import { I18nProvider, SSRProvider, useLocale } from 'react-aria';
import './globals.css';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
  params,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: { locale: string };
}) {
  const { locale, direction } = useLocale();

  // Show a 404 error if the user requests an unknown locale
  if (params.locale !== locale) {
    notFound();
  }
  return (
    <SSRProvider>
      <I18nProvider locale={locale}>
        <html lang={locale} dir={direction}>
          <body className={inter.className}>
            <h1>Merhaba</h1>
            <LanguageSwitcher />
            {children}
          </body>
        </html>
      </I18nProvider>
    </SSRProvider>
  );
}
```

But I am getting an error. Am I doing something wrong? Version "next": "13.4.4",

[React aria server-side rendering](https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/ssr.html#locale-selection)

[image]